# Prevent Windows Server 2012 from using DHCP-provided default gateway?

Tags: routing, dhcp, gateway

How can I prevent Windows Server 2012's local network connection from using the default gateway provided by a DHCP server?  I do not control the DHCP server so the solution must be implemented on the client machine.

I remember registry entries `DontAddDefaultRoute` and `DontAddDefaultGateway` in Windows NT.  These don’t seem to work now.

Comment: Does your question pertain to when the server's LAN interface is getting its DHCP lease, or when getting a DHCP lease when making a VPN connection from the server?

Comment: LAN interface is getting its DHCP lease

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default gateway provided via a DHCP lease by running the following two commands from an elevated Command Prompt (adapted from this Technet [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7faf392a-ce91-4589-b5a7-9383181dc610/how-to-manually-define-gateway-address-with-dhcp)):

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <DHCP_GATEWAY_IP>
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <NEW_GATEWAY_IP>
```

If you don't want *any* default route, simply omit the `route add` command.

This change will not persist across reboots, so it will be necessary to run this command on computer startup.  I suggest using [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to run this as a task each time the computer starts.

Comment: already using it, thought there's another way thats why mentioned registry entries

Comment: or maybe there's something like local dhcp bridge that will filter leases

Comment: You should add this, and anything else you're already tried, to your question. No need to get answers suggesting what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Route Add command followed by -p switch (Persistent)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip \Parameters\PersistentRoutes

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323(v=ws.10).aspx